# dpkg --configure -a stuck at "setting up base-files (10.1ubuntu2)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

I have been using ubuntu since version 8.04.

I start to loosing faith in this distribution.

I was on 17.10 for a while, until one day, after I upgraded, the OS no longer boots.

The error was

Wlp6s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware

After a week trying to get it to work, I decided to upgrade my laptop to 18.04 and hoping that new kernel will resolve the problem.  I cant just idling and hoping someone will patch the kernel bug.    I have work to do and this is my primary laptop.

So, i drop to root shell in recovery, did my usual things

do-release-upgrade

then, it stuck at this line

```
setting up base-file (10.1ubuntu2)...
```

I went to look for /var/log/dpkg.log

it doesn't give me any more information:

```
status half-configured base-file:amd 10.1ubuntu2
```

the aptitude log has a line

```
[UNCONFIGURED] base-file:amd64 10.1ubuntu2
```

My question for you is.

what is this 10.1ubuntu2?  how do i somehow un-stuck this?

thanks

Comment: did you resolve this? i have the same problem

Comment: No.  and trust me, I tried just about everything.

I end up deleting entire linux root partition (/) and started over.

Since my /home is in a different partition, this is not as bad as I thought. 

I recommend you simply back up your /home directory (if it is in the same directory), back up other stuff in /etc (which I didn't).

what i did lost was all the software i've installed in past a decade,  I just reinstall them as I encounter the need.  pain, but consider that most of customization is in my /home directory, it wasn't that bad.